# jQuery ajax inside loop works very slowly

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops

I have next situation. In html I have 6 placeholders for images which I want to load dynamically:

```
 <div class="block">
     <div class="block_content" data-category="sport">
 </div>
 ... 5 more blocks
```

As I wrote - I want to load picture dynamically:

```
$('._block_content').each(function() {
        let $imageBlock = $(this),
            category = $(this).data('category');

    $.ajax({
        url: here is URL,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function (data) {
            console.log('Success function loaded');
      },
      function () {
            console.log('Failed function loaded');
});
```

Now the problem is that such approach works well when pictures are found, and very slowly when not. If for example I will put wrong URL, first I will get 6 times **error net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED** and only then *failed functions* will be called. I need to wait near 3 seconds to get *failed functions* called.
Is there any way I can make async ajax requests inside loop more fast? Any ideas?

Comment: The problem what u doing is not asking the ajax if was done or not u just running 2 another function after ajax no matter what happened.
U should use for that `success: function ()` and `error: function ()` or `complete: function()`

Comment: No, you can't really make it faster. If it takes 3 seconds for the server to tell you the image doesn't exist, it's going to take 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to loop Ajax but have Ajax loop.

```
var categories=[],cnt=0;
function loadAjax() {
  if (cnt==categories.length) return;
  $.ajax({
    url: "here is URL?cat="+categories[cnt++],
    dataType: 'json'
  },
  success:function (data) {
    console.log('Success function loaded');
  },
  always:function() { loadAjax()  })
}

$('._block_content').each(function() {
   categories.push($(this).data('category'));
});
loadAjax();
```

Comment: wouldn't this just cause the delays to be stacked sequentially, thus resulting in the same outcome, but with a far longer delay?

Comment: Agree with @KevinB.. its gonna be slower than regular loop.

Comment: It will call again as soon as it can regardless of fail or success and it will not reach the browser limit if there are more than limit images

Comment: What do you mean? Also I make sure there are no concurrent Ajax which will fail for more than 6 concurrent requests

Comment: U printing out to console success message but no matter if it fails u calling the function again by doing `always: function` so the call should be in `success: function`

Comment: No. If there are 3 ok URLs and 3 not OK urls, the 3 OK URLs will succeed and not be stopped by the errors

Comment: I think @Kevin B has a point! If I remove 5 blocks and leave one block (thus leave one ajax request), delay is the same! So I believe delay is not because of bad code, but because of server response as Kevin wrote in comments!

Comment: Sure. But in my case you are not hammering the server while it is thinking about it

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for example you can use the browser cache or use a promise on your deffered response.

```
function img_async(source) {
  return $.Deferred (function (task) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {task.resolve(image);}
    image.onerror = function () {task.reject();}
    image.src=source;
  }).promise();
}
```

Inside your loop:

```
$.when(img_async(IMAGE_URL)).done(function (image) {
  $(this).empty().append(image);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this, calling .ajax() should return a jqXHR object:
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

I believe this should solve your problem:

```
$.ajax({
        url: here is URL,
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
           // do stuff
      })
      .fail(function() {
    alert( "$.get failed!" );
  });
```

Comment: As I know: $.ajax().then (function, function) is equivalent of done/fail pair.

Comment: Ah, I will look for a better answer.